# Two fact tables with same hierachy but different granularity

Tags: data-warehouse

Suppose the following hypothetical situation where we need two Fact tables defined as:

**Evaluation fact table**

- UserID
- SchoolID
- CourseID
- Status (passed/not passed)

**UserResponse Fact table**

- UserID
- SchoolID
- CourseID
- SubjectID
- SurveyID
- Response

It's clear that we need a User dimension table, but how would be modelling the another hiercarhy dimension?

The two possible approaches that we have are:

1 - Model all the dimensions separately and relate them to each other (snowflake schema) and relate de fact table to the corresponding dimension. In this case we need multiple joins when build a query.

2 - Following the kimball recommendation, we should unify all 1:n relations in a unique dimension but with this aproximation we should build two dimensions that contain same information but with different granularity:

**dim Survey**

- ID
- SurveyDescription
- SubjectID
- SubjectDescription
- CourseID
- CourseDescription
- SubjectID
- SubjectDescription
- SchoolID
- SchoolDescription

**dimCourse**

- ID
- CourseDescription
- SubjectID
- SubjectDescription
- SchoolID
- SchoolDescription

Which approach is more appropiate?

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you create your data model like this:
If you have specific questions about how to populate each table, provide sample data, we might help.

[image: sample model]

Update: According to your question below, you can find answers like these with this model, assuming user is same as student
(added schoolName to dim_school table)

This query below will give you the answer for how many students there are in a school based on the data you have in your fact_evaluation table.
If you ask in general how many students there are in a particular school you need more info like enrollments etc.

```
select schoolName, count(distinct userID)
from fact_evaluation f
join dim_school d on d.schoolID = f.schoolID
where schoolName = <a school name>
group by 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mdem7, but this approach is not feasible because our fact table is a transaction fact table so we will not have all the possible relationships reflected. For example if I wanted to know how many students there are in a school, I would need the relationship between school and student and this model not provide to us. Any idea with this problem?

Comment: Updated my answer above according to your question, let me know if you have any other questions.